# set isTouchInside to false

Tags: ios, swift

I need to check if UITextField has received some kind of focus such as isTouchInside then after the code in the if statement is executed i want to set the isTouchInside to false. Is this possible? Or something else should be used here?

I want to add 3 different values to the array when the textfield is selected by user. When i do it like below and touch the txt1 and after that txt2. txt 1 is also added to the array and i don't want that to happen

```
if self.txt1.isTouchInside{ //this sets isTouchInside to true
    print("txt1 touched")
    self.array.append(value1)
    //how to set isTouchInside to false here?

 }else if self.txt2.isTouchInside{
    print("txt2 touched")
    self.array.append(value2)
    //how to set isTouchInside to false here?
 }else if self.txt3.isTouchInside{
    print("txt3 touched")
    self.array.append(value3)
   //how to set isTouchInside to false here?
}
```

Comment: No, [it's read-only](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicontrol/1618229-istouchinside). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I edited the question, hope its clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a read-only property. You can't change the value of `isTouchInside`. Full stop. not possible.

Explain what you are trying to accomplish at a higher level and perhaps we can help you.